# Has Sanji mutated?

Tags: one-piece

So from the recent manga chapters I know that

> Sanji is the third son of the vinsmoke family and like his brothers he undergone a surgery as a fetus and has had his genes mutated. But due to drug his mother took he developed compassion and did not mutate while he was with his family.

So has he mutated over the course of his adventure or would this be a place for him to gain power from in the future?

Answer (score 1):

He may have in some capacity and that may be revealed as the current arc (whole cake island) progresses. But currently no he is not mutated.

His father states this during their battle when he first left the straw hats, calling him weak and stating that he is suprised that Sanji is even able to use haki in his form.

During that battle and the other scuffles he's had with other siblings too, I'm sure that if he had undergone some sort of mutation it would have been brought to light by now.

In summation, Sanji is regarded by his father and siblings as the failed project because the mutation never took effect on him.

Comment: It never took effect when he was a child, I was wondering if he has mutated to some extend (not like his siblings and not full mutation) and oda plans to use his modified body to give him immense power at some point

Comment: @Henjin I haven't seen any commentary from Oda on that but if something like that is in the works. It will come out towards the climax of the whole cake island arc. I doubt it because if he had any potential the emotional uprise he had when he fought his father should have made it apparent which it didn't. Guess best option is to wait and see.

Answer (score 1):

He did. However, we remember that his mother took the drug on all her children. It never had effect except a bit with Reiju and mostly with Sanji. Even though, the drug became less significant when Sanji learned from Seff the RedLeg. His power fully awakens when he battles Jabra. The first sign was his [fire leg](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/38852/one-piece-manga-sanjis-flame-powerspoiler-if-not-caught-up/38870#38870). However, after all this time, his emotions as a human being are not affected by the mutation.

Comment: PS. Jabra is the wolf from CP9.

Comment: You made the assumption that the mutation was the cause of his sudden gain of power, but in my opinion, it is rather is intense training and the tension during Robin's rescue that made him stronger.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read and seen, no, Sanji is not and will not mutate.

His mother had a drug injected into him during pregnancy to make the children specifically super human from birth. But Sanji's mother took a counteracting drug and Sanji was born without the strength boost. It's stated in the manga that that is why he is treated that way, I'm pretty sure.